# Wrap ALL Javascript code in an IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

Is it possible to wrap **all** your Javascript code, no matter how long it is, in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)? If yes, what are the potential pros and cons?

Comment: You obviously know what an IIFE is. What are the pros and cons of using one? That's your answer regardless of loc.

Comment: Arbitrarily long? No, computers don't have an infinite memory to store your program.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are "ways" to do it. You could write your whole code in a single file (not recommended for non-trivial applications), or use some processor to combine all your javascript files into one (common when minifying files).
  As for "should" you do it, it has it's benefits of course, it means you could write unscoped functions, like

```
function globalFunc(){}
```

And it wouldn't pollute the global namespace. This could be done to avoid exposing functions and thus prevent users from calling them through the console. Of course you'd need to scope all variables and methods you DO want to expose with `window.`, which I believe is a good practice anyway.